How to set file dates before 1970 on network drive?
Server is macOS 14 on a Mac Mini M2
Desktop is an intel iMac running macOS 14
I am able to set the "Date Modified" of a file locally to April 10 1957 using touch -d 1957-04-1018:47:00

When I try the touch command from the network on the same file I get a "Date Modified" year 2262.

I found info on Wikipedia which I think means that some timekeeping systems count nanoseconds since 1970. It's the same touch command. The question is what intermediary software is goofing up the translation?
Wikipedia has that listed in their "Time format Bugs"
"If you're using a remote file system, then there's gonna be another layer of translation where things can go awry. That's probably where the 2262 dates are introduced, as signed integer negative time stamps are misinterpreted as unsigned integer positive time stamps at some point."

From my testing the issue is with the macOS SMB server.  Reasons:

Using macOS 14.6.1 with APFS volumes directly (no network involved) touch -d "1968-04-09 18:47:00" test.txt correctly sets the date to before 1970.

Using macOS 14.6.1 with APFS volume using an SMB network connection to itself: touch -d "1968-04-09 18:47:00" /Volumes/gilby/test.txt where /Volumes/gilby is the network volume - this shows the error (messed up date).

But with an SMB network connection to Ubuntu with ext4 volume touch -d "1968-04-09  18:47:00" /Volumes/home/gilby/test.txt does not show the error - the date is correctly set to before 1970.


The messed up date only occurs when the connection is to a macOS SMB share (not to a Ubuntu share) leading me to conclude that the macOS SMB server is the likely culprit.
Resolution can only be for Apple to consider this worth fixing (which I rather doubt).
Edit: Enabling the NFS server for file sharing and making connection using NFS does nothing to resolve the issue with dates before 1970 being set incorrectly. But differently incorrect!
